# DOJO StoreExplorer not displaying correctly

Tags: json, dojo

I have a very simple example of an html that calls a jsp page that returns a very simple JSON object.   My problem is that what I expect the screen to show is not being displayed.

Here is a screen shot of what I see.

[image: screenshot]
[screen shot link](http://www.flickr.com/photos/sky_dive_bound/4274347238/sizes/l/)

Here is the relevent parts of the HTML file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/dojo/dojo.js"  
 djConfig="isDebug:false,parseOnLoad:true"></script>

<script>
            dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");
            dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");
            dojo.require("dojo.parser");
            dojo.require("dijit.form.TextBox");
            dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
            dojo.require("dojox.data.StoreExplorer");

            var jsonStore; 

            dojo.xhrGet({
                url: "json.jsp",
                handleAs: "json",
                //handleAs: "text",
                load: populateDiv,
                error: function(type, data, evt){alert("error");}

            });
        function populateDiv(dataItems) {
            console.log(dataItems);
            jsonStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore(dataItems); 
        } 
</script>
<div id="strexplr" dojoType="dojox.data.StoreExplorer" store="jsonStore" 
     style="height:500px;width:100%;border:1px solid black"/>
```

Here is my JSP page. (forgive the formatting)

        `<%@ page language="java" contentType="application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
        <%@ taglib prefix="json" uri="http://www.atg.com/taglibs/json" %>`

```
<json:object>
     <json:property name="identifier" value="customer_name"></json:property>
     <json:property name="label" value="customer_address"></json:property>

     <json:array name="items" var="item" items="2">
         <json:object>
             <json:property name="customer_name" value="nancy"></json:property>
             <json:property name="customer_address" value="LA"></json:property>
         </json:object>
         <json:object>
            <json:property name="customer_name" value="ken"></json:property>
            <json:property name="customer_address" value="CA"></json:property>
         </json:object>
    </json:array>
</json:object>
```

Using the Firefox Plugin for JSON objects, I was able to determine I had a valid JSON object.   Here is the output from the JSP page using that plugin.

```
{
```

```
 identifier: "customer_name"
 label: "customer_address"


  items: [
        {
             customer_name: "nancy"
             customer_address: "LA"
        }
        {
             customer_name: "ken"
             customer_address: "CA"
        }
  ]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

looking at your screenshot - it seems you don't have a theme.  you need to link to the appropriate css for one of dijit's themes and then add the theme name as a class to the body of your html.

also, you should probably only set the store for the StoreExplorer after you create the store.

you could avoid your xhrGet by giving the url to the store directly.

take a look at [the store explorer test page](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.4.0/dojo-release-1.4.0/dojox/data/tests/stores/explore_ItemFileWriteStore.html) if you haven't done so already.

Comment: Here is my Body Tag.


<body class="tundra">
 <div id="strexplr" dojoType="dojox.data.StoreExplorer" structure="view1" store="store" 
    style="height:500px;width:100%;border:1px solid black"/> 
</body>

Comment: Here is my xhrGet..

dojo.xhrGet({
             url: "json.jsp",
             handleAs: "json",
             load: function(dataItems,ioArgs){
    console.log('=popdiv=');
    console.log(dataItems);
    console.log('=popdiv=');
       console.log(dataItems.items[0].customer_name);
    store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore(dataItems);
    return dataItems; 
   },
             error: function(type, data, evt){alert("error");}
                    
        });

Comment: BTW..  console.log(dataItems.items[0].customer_name);  returns Nancy.

Again sorry for the formatting, I am pretty new to this particular forum, so I am on a learning curve as for the proper tags to use.

Comment: Oh and I get the same look without the data grid or the tree.